# How should I calculate $\lim_{x\to 0} x\csc(x)+\frac{1}{x \csc(x)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

> How should I calculate $\lim_{x\to 0} x\csc(x)+\frac{1}{x \csc(x)}$?

**THOUGHTS**:

I am not sure how to solve this problem. I tried breaking the problem down into two different limits:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} x\csc(x)+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x \csc(x)}
$$

since if I can handle this two limits, then I can sum them together to get the desired result according to one of the [limit properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Properties).

However, when evaluating the limits as $x$ approaches $0$, I get an indeterminate form.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$x \csc x+\frac1{x \csc x} = \frac{x}{\sin x}+\frac1{\frac{x}{\sin x}}=\frac{x}{\sin x}+\frac{\sin x}{x}$$

then use that

- [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)